# Extract JIRA Issues Using Excel VBA on Mac Office 2011

Tags: excel, macos, vba, jira

I've been searching high an low for a way to port my JIRA extraction VBA code over to mac.

I know this has been asked before but there is no clear answer and I am hoping someone can help me to understand how I can replicate the MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 object as I know this cannot be instantiated on the mac using vba in excel.

```
Dim JiraService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim JiraAuth As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
```

As a result of the above, the compiler throws an error of course because it cannot parse the above.

Any ideas/solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to have a look at this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/need-xmlhttp-request-like-feature-in-excel-for-mac/f2b5aca7-fcbb-4c60-b606-27e1c4a0fcd9?auth=1  and this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/274787 - they suggest to use web queries instead